# How to validating user input with hasNext(); while?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm building a phone book program where it asks the user for a set of questions, Q1: Enter your name, Q2: Enter your username, Q3: Enter your number. I'm struggling to include exceptions in my program.

```
public void Q1(){
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the person: ");
        while (!scan.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
            scan.next();
        }
        firstName = scan.next();
    }while(firstName != null);
        Q2();
    }
```

Q2(); has practically the same code as Q1();. My problem here is validating user input and moving onto the next question.

Answer (score 0):

Build a method that verifies the string input if empty string entered by the user then print `invalid input` until getting valid one, and verify the string of the digits using the REGEX `\\d+` which means one digit or more, like this:

```
    String name, username;
    int number;

    public void Q1(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the person: ");
        name = readAndCheckString(scan);
    }

    public void Q2(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("Enter the username of the person: ");
        username = readAndCheckString(scan);
    }

    public void Q3(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("Enter number of the person: ");
        String numberString = readAndCheckDigit(scan);

        number = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
    }

    String readAndCheckString(Scanner scan) {
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        while ("".equals(input)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
            input = scan.nextLine();
        }
        return input;
    }

    String readAndCheckDigit(Scanner scan) {
        String numberString = scan.nextLine();
        // if numberString is empty or not digit then print invalid
        while ("".equals(numberString) || !numberString.matches("\\d+")) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
            numberString = scan.nextLine();
        }
        return numberString;
    }
```

Comment: What are the methods String readAndCheck?  Also, you've assigned number to Integer.parseInt(numberString); . Could you explain what that's doing?

Comment: `readAndCheck()` this will read the input string and check if it's empty and get the valid input string for `name` and `username`

Comment: I don't know if you are using `number` variable as string or integer, I deal with it as integer

Comment: Hey, I've broken the code into two methods, 'Q1()' and 'readAndCheckString'. It doesn't seem to output Invalid Input. It was only when I edited what's between the quotation marks in the while loop.  Nevertheless, I do like the new way of checking for digits.

Comment: `"".equals(numberString)` this means that if the user didn't type anything and hit enter

Comment: So I guess it didn't print anything because you change the condition

Comment: I tried to hit enter and a new line appeared and it kept appearing, it was only when I assigned the "" to a "string" and entered string, Invalid input was looped